# MYSQL Select from 2 tables with an id that is in just in one of them

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This is my question:
I have 3 tables:

```
USERS

USERS_INFO

COMPANIES_INFO
```

The `USERS` table has a field `ID`
The tables `USERS_INFO` and `COMPANIES_INFO` have a field `ID_USER` that is linked by a foreign key with `ID`.

The question is, how can I select a row that is present in just one of them?

An example:

```
USERS
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  | 
+----+
| 2  | 
+----+

USERS_INFO
+---------+---------+
| id_user | name    |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | Jhonny  |
+---------+---------+


COMPANIES_INFO
+---------+---------+
| id_user | company |
+---------+---------+
| 2       | Apple   |
+---------+---------+
```

What I want is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users_info, companies_info WHERE id_user=2
```

And get this:

```
id_user = 2
company = Apple
```

Instead if I did

```
SELECT * FROM users_info, companies_info WHERE id_user=1
```

I would have got:

```
id_user =1
name = Jhonny
```

I want for example select the user 2, by checking both tables `USERS_INFO` and `COMPANIES_INFO` because we don't know which one contains it...
Any help?

Comment: to me this sounds like something is wrong with your schema design, if a user is one type vs the other is usually presented with a field in the same table called `user_type_id`

Comment: Then I will suggest you to restructure your table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     SELECT U.id
     FROM users U
     LEFT JOIN users_info UI ON U.id = CI.id_user
     LEFT JOIN companies_info CI ON U.id = CI.id_user
     WHERE UI.id IS NOT NULL AND CI.id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```sql
SET @user = 1;
SELECT id_user, name FROM USERS_INFO WHERE id_user = @user
UNION
SELECT id_user, company as name FROM COMPANIES_INFO WHERE id_user = @user;
```